# Problema com in_array()

Tags: php, array, array-associativo

Estou com um problema com a função in_array.

Fiz um `var_dump()` na array que quero procurar:

```
array(2) { 
    ["28c8edde3d61a0411511d3b1866f0636"]=> array(8) { 
        ["id"]=> string(32) "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b" 
        ["qty"]=> float(1) 
        ["price"]=> float(2500) 
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Album: Xim-ER" 
        ["type"]=> string(5) "Asset" 
        ["weight"]=> string(3) "115" 
        ["rowid"]=> string(32) "28c8edde3d61a0411511d3b1866f0636" 
        ["subtotal"]=> float(2500) 
    } 
    ["dc74f1aaf0e81b424c56cbd906f3d3c3"]=> array(8) { 
        ["id"]=> string(33) "Dc4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b" 
        ["qty"]=> float(1) 
        ["price"]=> float(2000) 
        ["name"]=> string(21) "Album: Xim-ER Digital" 
        ["type"]=> string(7) "Digital" 
        ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["rowid"]=> string(32) "dc74f1aaf0e81b424c56cbd906f3d3c3" 
        ["subtotal"]=> float(2000) 
    }
}
```

Preciso ver nessa Array se eu tenho Asset, então eu fiz o seguinte no meu controller:

```
<?php

$order->Shipping = new stdClass ();
if (in_array ( array ('type','Asset'), $cart_array )) {
    $order->Shipping->Type = 'Correios';
    $order->Shipping->SourceZipCode = '25670202';
    $order->Shipping->TargetZipCode = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_cep' );
    $order->Shipping->Address = new stdClass ();
    $order->Shipping->Address->Street = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress' );
    $order->Shipping->Address->Number = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress_number' );
    $order->Shipping->Address->Complement = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress_comp' );
    $order->Shipping->Address->District = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress_district' );
    $order->Shipping->Address->City = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_city' );
    $order->Shipping->Address->State = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_state' );
} else {
    $order->Shipping->Type = 'WithoutShipping';
}
```

Porém ele só retorna o shipping com WithoutShipping.

Esqueci algum parâmetro para fazer o in_array corretamente?

Answer (score 4):

Consegui dar um jeito.
Na verdade usa-se um in_array e um array_column pra especificar o array.

```
if(in_array('Asset', array_column($cart_array, 'type'))){}
```

Comment: Faz Sentido, por que para que o in_array funcione é necessário um "tipo simples" e o array é tipo complexo, com o array_column, restringe-se o tipo de dado verificado pelo in_array.

Comment: Observação: `array_column` só está disponível a partir do PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

O problema no meu ponto de vista é que voce está procurando um array dentro de outro, pelo que entendi voce quer ver dentro do array $cart_arry se existe um objeto do tipo Asset, mas o in_array pelo que entendi não vai de ajudar nisso, ele serve para procurar um valor dentro do array, e não para verificar o tipo dos itens do array, não achei nada na internet que faça isso com o in_array

```
$myArray = array("Audi","BMW","Lexus","Mercedes");

var_dump($myArray);

if (in_array("Lexus", $myArray)) {
    echo "Lexus was found in the array<br/>";
}

if (in_array("opel", $myArray)) {
    echo "Opel was found in the array<br/>";
}
```

Para isso que voce quer talvez tenha que fazer de outra forma, correr esta lista e verificar o tipo.

Espero ter ajudado a esclarecer sua duvida.

Comment: Olá Cristian, muito obrigado pela atenção. Entendi por partes, a questão é como eu iria correr na array e depois verificar? Eu pensei em condições e tudo mais. O problema é que pela lógica, era muito mais simples se o in_array() me retornasse já. Pois querendo ou não é um valor que está na array.

Answer (score 1):

Há um jeito fácil para procurar recursivamente por um valor em um array multidimensional que funciona em todas as versões do PHP 5.

```
/**
 * @param $needle
 * @param $haystack
 * @param bool $strict
 *  Função in_array recursiva - Mantido mesma assinatura que in_array para facilitar uso
 */
function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $found = $strict == false ? $needle == $value : $needle === $value;
        if ($found == false) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                return in_array_recursive($needle, $value, $strict);
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Aqui funcionando no seu código.

```
$cart_array = array(
    "28c8edde3d61a0411511d3b1866f0636" => array(
        "id" => "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",
        "qty" => (float)1,
        "price" => (float)2500,
        "name" => "Album: Xim-ER",
        "type" => "Asset",
        "weight" => "115",
        "rowid" => "28c8edde3d61a0411511d3b1866f0636",
        "subtotal" => (float)2500,
    ),
    "dc74f1aaf0e81b424c56cbd906f3d3c3" => array(
        "id" => "Dc4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",
        "qty" => (float)1,
        "price" => (float)2000,
        "name" => "Album: Xim-ER Digital",
        "type" => "Digital",
        "weight" => "0",
        "rowid" => "dc74f1aaf0e81b424c56cbd906f3d3c3",
        "subtotal" => (float)2000,
    )
);

if (in_array_recursive('Asset', $cart_array)) {
   echo 'WithShipping';
} else {
    echo 'WithoutShipping';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está verificando um array multidimensional e o `in_array()` não é recursivo, ou seja, ele não irá procurar o valor no segundo nível do array.

Antes de fazer a verificação faça um loop para iterar o array:

```
<?php

$order->Shipping = new stdClass ();

foreach ( $cart_array as $cart_item ) {
    if (in_array ( array('type','Asset'), $cart_item )) {
        $order->Shipping->Type = 'Correios';
        $order->Shipping->SourceZipCode = '25670202';
        $order->Shipping->TargetZipCode = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_cep' );
        $order->Shipping->Address = new stdClass ();
        $order->Shipping->Address->Street = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress' );
        $order->Shipping->Address->Number = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress_number' );
        $order->Shipping->Address->Complement = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress_comp' );
        $order->Shipping->Address->District = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_adress_district' );
        $order->Shipping->Address->City = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_city' );
        $order->Shipping->Address->State = $this->session->userdata ( 'user_state' );
    } else {
        $order->Shipping->Type = 'WithoutShipping';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dois problemas:

- Você esta tentando verificar uma `chave` sendo que o `in_array` busca por valores.
- Você tem um `array` bidimensional, e esta tentando verificar os conteúdo mais interno.

#### Possível soluções

```
foreach ($cart_array as $key => $options){
    if(in_array(array('type','Asset'), array_keys($options)){
        # Código aqui
    }
}
```